# Invalid type in utility function 'lerp'. Cannot convert argument 2 from float to Nil

Tags: godot, lerp

Here's a declaration of *Vector2* `camera_input`. And, it comes out to be invalid. I'm using Godot 4.0.1.

Code:

```
extends CanvasLayer

@onready var camguide_y = get_parent().get_node("character_1_controller/camguide_y")
@onready var camguide_x = get_parent().get_node("character_1_controller/camguide_y/camguide_x")

var joystick_index = -1
var attack_index = -1
var s1_index = -1
var s2_index = -1
var dodge_index = -1
var camera_index = -1
var camera_input = Vector2.ZERO
var rotation_velocity_x = 0
var rotation_velocity_y = 0

func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event is InputEventScreenTouch:
        if event.pressed:
            if Input.is_action_just_pressed("joystick_action"):
                joystick_index = event.index
            elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("attack_action"):
                attack_index = event.index
            elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("s1_action"):
                s1_index = event.index
            elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("s2_action"):
                s2_index = event.index
            elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("dodge_action"):
                dodge_index = event.index
            else:
                camera_index = event.index
        else:
            if Input.is_action_just_released("joystick_action"):
                joystick_index = -1
            elif Input.is_action_just_released("attack_action"):
                attack_index = -1
            elif Input.is_action_just_released("s1_action"):
                s1_index = -1
            elif Input.is_action_just_released("s2_action"):
                s2_index = -1
            elif Input.is_action_just_released("dodge_action"):
                dodge_index = -1
            else:
                camera_index = -1
    if event is InputEventScreenDrag:
        if event.index == joystick_index:
            pass
        if event.index == camera_index:
            camera_input = event.relative
        
        
        
# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    rotation_velocity_x = lerp(rotation_velocity_x, camera_input.x * 0.4, delta*10.0)
    rotation_velocity_y = lerp(rotation_velocity_y, camera_input.y * 0.15, delta*10.0)
    camguide_x.rotate_x(deg_to_rad(rotation_velocity_y))
    camguide_y.rotate_y(deg_to_rad(rotation_velocity_x))
    camguide_x.rotation.x = clamp(camguide_x.rotation.x, -0.5, 0.5)
    camera_input = Vector2.ZERO
```

Error message:
Invalid type in utility function 'lerp'. Cannot convert argument 2 from float to Nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [lerp documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@globalscope.html#class-globalscope-method-lerp):

> `Variant lerp ( Variant from, Variant to, Variant weight )`
>
> ...
>
> Both `from` and `to` *must be the same type*.

`camera_input.x` is a float (because that's what `Vector2.ZERO` is made up of) whereas `rotation_velocity_x` is inferred as an int (because `0` is an integer).

Try changing the declaration to:

```
var rotation_velocity_x = 0.0
```

or better yet use static typing:

```
var rotation_velocity_x : float = 0.0
```

Comment: It. works, thank you so much, I have tried to focus on camera_input and ignored the rotation velocity.