# Godot Velocity: Invalid type in utility function "lerp", cannot convert arg 2 from Vector2 to float on line 40

Tags: vector, lerp, floating-point, godot-4

I'm trying to solve a lerp problem on my velocity, searched some stuff here and there, but found nothing that solved it. Can you help me?

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@export_category("Variables")
@export var _movespeed: float = 64.0
@export var _acceleration: float = 0.4 #Atraso na aceleração do personagem
@export var _friction: float = 0.8 #Desaceleração mais rápida

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    _move()
    move_and_slide()
    
func _move() -> void:
    var _direction:Vector2 = Vector2(
        Input.get_axis("move_left", "move_right"),
        Input.get_axis("move_up", "move_down")
    )
        
    print(_direction)
    
    if _direction != Vector2.ZERO:
        velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, (_direction.normalized() * _movespeed), _acceleration)
        velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y, (_direction.normalized() * _movespeed), _acceleration)
        return

    velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, (_direction.normalized() * _movespeed), _friction)
    velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y, (_direction.normalized() * _movespeed), _friction)
    
    velocity = (_direction.normalized() * _movespeed)
```

- ([Invalid type in utility function 'lerp'. Cannot convert argument 2 from float to Nil](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/205244/invalid-type-in-utility-function-lerp-cannot-convert-argument-2-from-float-to))
  Already tried this answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to lerp between a float (velocity.x) and a Vector2 (_direction). Try accessing the x and y params of the _direction Vector2 for lerping:

```
func _move() -> void:
    if _direction != Vector2.ZERO:
        velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, (_direction.normalized().x * _movespeed), _acceleration)
        velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y, (_direction.normalized().y * _movespeed), _acceleration)
        return

    velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, (_direction.normalized().x * _movespeed), _friction) # Normalizing a ZERO Vector2?
    velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y, (_direction.normalized().y * _movespeed), _friction) # Normalizing a ZERO Vector2?
    
    velocity = (_direction.normalized() * _movespeed) # Normalizing a ZERO Vector2? + Overwrites previous changes to the velocity?
```

the Code below the return statement seems to be incorrect aswell as you're trying to normalize the _direction Vector2 which is a Vector2.ZERO at this point. I'm not sure how Godot handles that.

Comment: Why do the lerp in two steps, one per component, instead of all at once? e.g. `velocity = lerp(velocity, _direction.normalized() * _movespeed, _acceleration)` ? Godot treats normalizing a zero vector as a no-op, so the second batch of lerps is equivalent to `velocity = velocity * (1 - _friction)` and the last line just sets velocity to zero, so the previous lines are redundant.

Comment: Yep, when normalizing the velocity on last line, we get -1,0,1 based on direction, multiplied by 64.0 (frame movement speed), it will normalize the Zero Vector only when the character doesn't make any moves

Comment: Also, thanks for correcting my syntax on lerp functions, I'm following a Godot tutorial to learn the basics, but the code of the instructor is kinda different, but it also works :( maybe it's a version difference

Comment: While normalizing a zero vector gives you a zero vector...  You might still want to check if it is approximately zero. Because then the small error will be blown up. In fact, it might give you something that is not normalized. See https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/74852